# ruby on rails shorten if in 1 line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, function, line

The `code` that i am trying to `shorten` in `one line`:

```
            if !request.xhr?
                    render_404
                    return
            end
```

from this function

```
def request_invite
    render_404 unless request.xhr?

        @invitation = Invite.new(params[:invite])

        if @invitation.save
            @return = { :error => false, :response => "OK" }
        else
            @return = { :error => true, :response => @invitation.errors.full_messages.join("<br />") } 
        end

        render :json => ActiveSupport::JSON.encode( @return )

end
```

i tried

```
            render_404 return unless request.xhr?
```

but i get:

```
invites_controller.rb:4: void value expressio render_404 return unless request.xhr?
```

Should i stick with the above code that works or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need the `return`? The function body does not contains anything else. If it does, please note it.

```
def request_invite
   render_404 unless request.xhr?
end
```

The main problem is that you can't write the two command in one line without separation, it tries to evaluate it, but it is syntactically incorrect.

UPDATE:

```
def request_invite
    unless request.xhr? then render_404; return; end

    @invitation = Invite.new(params[:invite])

    if @invitation.save
        @return = { :error => false, :response => "OK" }
    else
        @return = { :error => true, :response => @invitation.errors.full_messages.join("<br />") } 
    end

    render :json => ActiveSupport::JSON.encode( @return )

end
```

Comment: it actually does, i updated it.. i didnt know it was needed thats why i didnt include it first

Comment: it seems to work... however i find it a bit less easier to read than the one using the if statement... anyway thanks

Comment: you can use `if !...` instead of unless, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
(render_404; return) unless request.xhr?
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
def request_invite
  render_404 return unless request.try(:xhr?)
end
```